# largest samples of set of random variables

Tags: time-complexity

Suppose we have two discrete random variables and we want perform maximum operation to obtain the max PDF.

We know that max of two independent random variables is: if $Z = max(X,Y)$

$pr(Z = k) = pr(X = k) pr(Y < k) + pr(X < k) pr(Y = k) + pr(X = k) pr(Y=k)$

[image: figure:]

Where in the above figure pr(Z=3) for instance is pr(X=3)*pr(Y=3)+ pr(X<3)pr(Y=3)+ pr(X=3)pr(Y<3) so (1)(1) + (1+1)(1) + (1)(1+1+1) =7.

My question how this operation has O(nm) timing complexity where n and m are the sample size of X and Y receptively or O(n^2) when both has n samples?

According to my calculations there is only 2 multiplications and n sums involve to generate each sample, so it should be o(n), right?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116022/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/425318/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right; the PDF of $Z=\max(X,Y)$ can be computed from the PDFs for $X,Y$ in $O(n+m)$ time, using the approach you described.

In particular, it takes $O(n)$ time to compute $P(X<x)$ for each $x$ ($n$ sums), $O(m)$ time to compute $P(Y<y)$ for each $y$ ($m$ sums), and $O(n+m)$ time to then compute $P(Z=z)$ for each $z$ (3 products and 2 sums for each of the possible values of $z$).

Perhaps that paper was using a sub-optimal algorithm, or maybe it was just a mistake, or maybe the author didn't care about the difference between $O(n+m)$ vs $O(nm)$ and used an overly loose bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please mention in what cases the complexity is quadratic? because other papers that cite this also mention that it is at the order of o(n^2)! I am not sure if it is a mistake! . Is it related to multiplication of two random variables which i think it take o(n^2) time.

Comment: @nauok, there aren't any cases; this always works.